# Use a non-class member as an event handler

Tags: eventhandler, c++builder-10.1-berlin

I'm writing a DLL wrapper to a C++Builder VCL class. This is an extremely simplified example of the problem:

```
typedef void __fastcall (__closure *TMyEvent)(int index);

class TMyClass {
  public:
    TMyEvent OnMyEvent;
};

void __fastcall myEventHandler(int index) { }

TMyClass myClass;
myClass.OnMyEvent = myEventHandler;
```

...and here is the problem:

Normally `myEventHandler` is defined inside another class, but here it is defined as a global function. When I try to assign `myEventHandler` to `myClass.OnMyEvent` I get an error

> Cannot convert void(int) to TMyEvent

I reuse the `TMyClass` to generate different kind of wrappers and need the `__closeure` in the `typedef` so it works well with VCL form projects.

Is the `__closure` the problem? Can I use a global function as an event handler at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `__closure` compiler extension is a special type of class method pointer that holds two pointers - a pointer to an object instance, and a pointer to the handler method.  When the `__closure` is executed, the compiler passes the object pointer to the handler via its `this` parameter.  As such, the handler MUST have a `this` parameter.

If the handler is a non-static member of a class, the `this` pointer is handled implicitly by the compiler for you, eg:

```
class TMyEvents {
public:
    void __fastcall myEventHandler(int index) { }
};

TMyClass myClass;
TMyEvents myEvents;
myClass.OnMyEvent = myEvents.myEventHandler;
```

If the handler is a standalone function, or is a static method of a class, then the `this` pointer must be provided in the parameter list explicitly.  In this situation, you can use the [`TMethod`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.TMethod)<sup>1</sup> struct to help you assign the handler to the event, eg:

```
void __fastcall myEventHandler(void *Data, int index) { }

TMethod m;
m.Data = ...; // can be anything you want to pass to the 'Data' parameter
m.Code = &myEventHandler;

TMyClass myClass;
myClass.OnMyEvent = reinterpret_cast<TMyEvent&>(m);
```

<sup>1</sup>: this only works with `__closure`!  Don't try to use it with other types of function pointers.